# Show existence of improper integral by convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, fake-proofs

Let be $f:[1,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ a monotonically decreasing function, $\int\limits_1^{\infty}f(x)dx$ an improper integral and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}f(k)$ a convergent series. For sake of simplicity let's assume that we already know that  $\int\limits_1^{t}f(x)dx\leq\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}f(k)$ for all $t\in (1,\infty)$. Our professor showed that  $\int\limits_1^{\infty}f(t)dt$ exists in a very strange way which I think is wrong.

---

**Professor's proof:**

We assume that $\int\limits_1^{\infty}f(x)dx$ is divergent. So we can conclude that there exists a sequence $\left(\beta_k\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\in(1,\infty)$ with $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\beta_k=\infty$ such that the sequence  $\left(b_k\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $b_k:=\int\limits_1^{\beta_k}f(x)dx$ is divergent. Let be $\left(\beta_k\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ monotonically increasing then it follows that $\left(b_k\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is also monotonically increasing. So $\left(b_k\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is monotone and bounded and hence convergent (due to monotone convergence theorem). This is a contradiction to the statement at the beginning so that $\int\limits_1^{\infty}f(x)dx$ must be convergent.

---

How is it possible to draw this conclusion if we only look at sequences $\left(\beta_k\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ that are monotonically increasing? I suspect that the professor has confused divergence with unboundedness which are not equivalent notions.

What if we include all sequences (also the non-monotone ones)? Then we can no longer make use of the monotone convergence theorem because it's not guaranteed that $b_k:=\int\limits_1^{\beta_k}f(x)dx$ remains monotonically increasing. Any help or comments are appreciated!

Comment: The improper integral is defined as a supremum of integrals over compact sets, so aren't you choosing the $\beta_n$?

Comment: You can choose a subsequence of $\beta_n$ which is monotnically increasing. So without loss of generality you can assume that the sequence is increasing, this is what your professor meant.

Comment: @stackex33 this is not the usual definition of an improper Riemann integral

Comment: @Jakobian Is it not? I should have added rectifiable perhaps. I was following Munkres' definition (from his Analysis on Manifolds). He defines the integral of an unsigned function over an open set to be the supremum of integrals over compact rectifiable subsets. In this case, I thought you can replace (by monotonicity of integrals) compact sets with closed intervals that bound the compact sets, and the right end points will work as the $\beta_n$.

Comment: @Jakobian why can the professor simply pick a monotonically increasing sequence $\left(\beta_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\beta_n=\infty$ without loss of generality? It might also be possible that $\int\limits_1^{\infty}f(x)dx$ does not exists because you find two sequences $\left(a_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $\left(b_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$, such that  $\int\limits_1^{a_n}f(x)dx \neq \int\limits_1^{b_n}f(x)dx$ as $n\to \infty$. And those sequences don't need to be monotonically increasing.

Comment: @Philipp even if the first sequence is not monotonic, you can take a monotonic subsequence and still get the same result. This is because when $f$ is nonnegative, $\int_1^a f\leq \int_1^b f$ whenever $a \leq b$.

Comment: @stackex33 Munkres gave a more general definition to prepare for Riemann integrals in multiple dimensions. Still, it's not the usual definition.

Comment: @Jakobian what is the usual definition? But it (Munkres' definition) is equivalent to $\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_1^\infty f$ when $f$ is nonnegative right?

Comment: @stackex33 Via Riemann sums or by upper/lower Darboux integrals. Then you define $\int_1^\infty f = \lim_{b\to\infty} \int_1^b f$

Comment: @Jakobian so they are the same, for nonnegative $f$. The definition I gave still requires Riemann/Darboux integral on compact sets. The limit you give is the supremum because  everything is monotonic. For general $f$, the supremum definition is not right, I agree.